# The following tasks did not complete. Did you forget to signal async completion? Tasks default, reset

Tags: javascript, node.js, веб-программирование, gulp, task

Есть файлы gulp-а

gulpfile.js

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const {path} = require('./gulp/config/path.js');
const {plugins} = require('./gulp/config/plugins.js');
/*
import gulp from "gulp";
import {path} from "./gulp/config/path.js";
import {plugins} from "./gulp/config/plugins.js";
*/

global.app = {
    isBuild: process.argv.includes('--build'),
    isDev: !process.argv.includes('--build'),
    path: path,
    gulp: gulp,
    plugins: plugins
}

// Имрорт задач
const copy = require("./gulp/tasks/copy.js");
const reset = require("./gulp/tasks/reset.js");
const html = require("./gulp/tasks/html.js");
const server = require("./gulp/tasks/server.js");
const scss = require("./gulp/tasks/scss.js");
const js = require("./gulp/tasks/js.js");
const images = require("./gulp/tasks/images.js");
const {otfToTtf, ttfToWoff, fontsStyle} = require("./gulp/tasks/fonts.js");
const svgSprive = require("./gulp/tasks/svgSprive.js");
const zip = require("./gulp/tasks/zip.js");
const ftp = require("./gulp/tasks/ftp.js");

/*
import {copy} from "./gulp/tasks/copy.js";
import {reset} from "./gulp/tasks/reset.js";
import {html} from "./gulp/tasks/html.js";
import {server} from "./gulp/tasks/server.js";
import {scss} from "./gulp/tasks/scss.js";
import {js} from "./gulp/tasks/js.js";
import {images} from "./gulp/tasks/images.js";
import {otfToTtf, ttfToWoff, fontsStyle} from "./gulp/tasks/fonts.js";
import {svgSprive} from "./gulp/tasks/svgSprive.js";
import {zip} from "./gulp/tasks/zip.js";
import {ftp} from "./gulp/tasks/ftp.js";
*/

function watcher() {
    gulp.watch(path.watch.files, copy);
    gulp.watch(path.watch.html, html);
    gulp.watch(path.watch.scss, scss);
    gulp.watch(path.watch.js, js);
    gulp.watch(path.watch.images, images);
}

// export {svgSprive}

const fonts = gulp.series(otfToTtf, ttfToWoff, fontsStyle);

const mainTasks = gulp.series(fonts, gulp.parallel(copy, html, scss, js, images));

const dev = gulp.series(reset, mainTasks, gulp.parallel(watcher, server));
const build = gulp.series(reset, mainTasks, svgSprive);
const deployZIP = gulp.series(reset, mainTasks, zip);
const deployFTP = gulp.series(reset, mainTasks, ftp);

/*
export {dev}
export {build}
export {deployZIP}
export {deployFTP}
*/

module.exports = { svgSprive, dev, build, deployZIP, deployFTP};

gulp.task('default', dev);
```

reset.js

```
/*import {
    deleteAsync
} from "del"*/

const del = require('del');

const reset = () => {
    async () => {
        const deletedPaths = await del(app.path.clean);
     
        // console.log('Deleted files and directories:\n', deletedPaths.join('\n'));
    }   
    
    // deleteAsync(app.path.clean)
}

module.exports = reset;
```

В результате выполнения команды gulp вылетают 2 красных сообщения: The following tasks did not complete. Did you forget to signal async completion?.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите как устранить эти сообщения.

Гуглил и нашел [The following tasks did not complete. Did you forget to signal async completion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36897877/gulp-error-the-following-tasks-did-not-complete-did-you-forget-to-signal-async), но у меня используется несколько другой синтаксис. Я пытался использовать вместо `gulp.task('default', dev);` `gulp.task('default',  async dev);`, но у меня подчеркивает красным `async dev`. Как с помощью правильного синтаксиса решить проблему?

Comment: См. [async-completion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76395674/the-following-tasks-did-not-complete-did-you-forget-to-signal-async-completion). Там указаны асинхронные задачи.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй вместо

```
const reset = () => {
    async () => {
        const deletedPaths = await del(app.path.clean);
     
        // console.log('Deleted files and directories:\n', deletedPaths.join('\n'));
    }   
    
    // deleteAsync(app.path.clean)
}
```

написать просто

```
const reset = async () => {
    const deletedPaths = await del(app.path.clean);
    // console.log('Deleted files and directories:\n', deletedPaths.join('\n'));
}
```